# Установить параметры письма MailMessage

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Есть система обменивающаяся данными при помощи электронных писем. 
Была произведена замена отправителя, сейчас письма отравляются через SMTP-Server.
Но принимающая сторона отказывается эти письма принимать, что-то не проходит.

Проанализировав письма предыдущего отправителя обнаружил следующие характеристики:

Содержание письма (Body):

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
```

Прилагаемый файл (Attachment):

```
Content-type: text/plain; name="..."
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="..."
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
```

Как установить эти параметры используя классы `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` и `System.Net.Mail.Attachment`

Comment: [раз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition(v=vs.110).aspx) [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx) [три](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024957/set-content-transfer-encoding-to-quoted-printable-with-net-mailmessage)

Answer (score 0):

я привязывал вот так:

```
//Для отправки почты
        static void SendMail()
        {
            string smtpHost = "хост почтовик";
            int smtpPort = порт;
            string login = "логин";
            string pass = "пароль";

            //connect
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort);
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, pass);

            //from-to-title-body message
            string from = "test@gmail.com";
            string to = "test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com";
            string subject = "Test header";
            string body = "Это тестовая рассылка, проверьте вложение";

            //attachment 
            Attachment attData = new Attachment(@"C:\test.xlsx");

            //create message and attaching
            MailMessage mess = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
            mess.Attachments.Add(attData);

            try
            {
                client.Send(mess);
                MessageBox.Show("Сообщение отправлено");
            }

            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex);
            }

        }
```